# How can i change variable value when i use media queries and scss

Tags: variables, sass, media-queries, font-size

I have same font-size variables in my site.
I want to change value of this variables when I use media queries in scss... How can i do it...
Below way doesn't exist...

```
@media screen and (min-width:1000px){
 $font-sm:      13px;
 $font-default: 15px;
 $font-md:      18px;
}
@media screen and (max-width:999px){
 $font-sm:      10px;
 $font-default: 12px;
 $font-md:      14px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use custom properties instead.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  :root {
    --font-sm: 13px;
    --font-default: 15px;
    --font-md: 18px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  :root {
    --font-sm: 10px;
    --font-default: 12px;
    --font-md: 14px;
  }
}

body {
  font-size: var(--font-default);
}
```